# Join Two Tables based on a Date Range

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I have two tables in my Firebird DB. The first table is called LEDGER and is showing the details of my transaction, including the date of of a transaction (yyyy/mm/dd). The second table is called PERIODS and consists of the following fields:

- Period number (INTEGER)
- Period start date (yyyy/mm/dd)
- Period end date (yyyy/mm/dd)

I want use the date as per the LEDGER table to look up the corresponding period from the PERIODS table and join the two tables based on that. I short, I want to show the period for each line of the ledger table to assist me in preparing consolidated reporting.

Herewith an example of the PERIODS table:

[image]

What would be the best approach to do this?

If I was the developer I would have added the period to the ledger table and populate the period on transactional level but unfortunately it is too late for that now.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the period the number of the week within the year?

Comment: A period is actually the month. So my database runs across three years, so ultimately there will be 36 periods

Comment: Is it just the month or month and year?

Comment: It is just the month. So the period numbers will be 1 through to 36

Comment: So what is your start date value?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The start date will be the first day of the month and the end date will be the last day of the month. I have edited my original question and added an example of the PERIODS table to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `join`:

```
select l.*, p.per
from ledger l left join
     periods p
     on l.date_of_transaction >= p.start_date and
        l.date_of_transaction <= p.end_date
```

Comment: Thank you for the below. My feeling is that Jim Macaulay's solution below is slightly easier. Do you have any concerns that it might not work?

Comment: @gdekoker . . . Yeah.  It won't work unless the `ledger` dates match the "start of period" dates.  I have no expectation that is the case.  It seems to me that a ledger entry could be on any date during a month.

Comment: Thanks. It is actually quite odd. If I use Jim Macaulay's solution on just joining two tables it works. However, when adding a third table I need to use your solution for it to work. Thanks, I am all sorted.

Comment: You can also use `l.date_of_transaction between p.start_date and p.end_date`

Answer (score 0):

Use below query. Please change the columns names, i have provided the column names as an example.

```
select P.PER, L.* from LEDGER L
inner join PERIODS P
on (L.date_of_transaction = P.start_date);



select P.PER, L.* from LEDGER L
inner join PERIODS P
on (L.date_of_transaction between P.start_date);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it can only look up the period if it is exactly the same as the start date, not when it falls within the period.

Comment: In that case you can use between caluse